WPF C# how to bind StyleTrigger to certain "offset" column multible times
Example of Simple Binding, I'm trying trying to style the Dates:

I only managed to color the color code itself but not the Dates based on the color code.
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ElementStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Text" Value="7">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>


<DataGridTextColumn Width="Auto" Header="Color_V1100" Binding="{Binding Color_V1100}"/>
<DataGridTextColumn Width="Auto" Header="V1500" Binding="{Binding V1500, StringFormat=dd.MM.yyyy}"/>
<DataGridTextColumn Width="Auto" Header="D_V1500" Binding="{Binding D_V1500}"/>
<DataGridTextColumn Width="Auto" Header="Status_V1500" Binding="{Binding Status_V1500}"/>
<DataGridTextColumn Width="Auto" Header="Color_V1500" Binding="{Binding Color_V1500}"/>
<DataGridTextColumn Width="Auto" Header="V1650" Binding="{Binding V1650, StringFormat=dd.MM.yyyy}" />
<DataGridTextColumn Width="Auto" Header="D_V1650" Binding="{Binding D_V1650}"/>
<DataGridTextColumn Width="Auto" Header="Status_V1650" Binding="{Binding Status_V1650}"/>
<DataGridTextColumn Width="Auto" Header="Color_V1650" Binding="{Binding Color_V1650}" ElementStyle="{StaticResource ElementStyle}"/>
<DataGridTextColumn Width="Auto" Header="V1800" Binding="{Binding V1800, StringFormat=dd.MM.yyyy}"/>
<DataGridTextColumn Width="Auto" Header="D_V1800" Binding="{Binding D_V1800}"/>


finally I will need the Dates (starting with "V") to always follow the column "Color_V..." but have no idea how to bind the properties nor values.
Any hint / link will be very much appreciated.
Best Regards
The Question is also which way to gather information?  IValueConverter, Templates, Resources, Relativesource...  I can hardly find any exact guideline for my problem.

I now managed to bind DataTrigger to ONE color code. But I am still not able to bind to the dedicated corresponding color code (Offset +3 Columns)

